# How to implement detection of a View being dragged over another view?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to have a draggable view, while being able to constantly monitor distance to the "target" view and to detect when draggable view is dragged over target view. My idea was to get `Rect's` of both views and to use `intersect()` to check if they are touching. However my implementation doesnt work smoothly - sometimes it detects overlap in wrong location or doesnt detect the end of overlapping. 
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe lead to correct way of doing it? (I cant use `startDrag()`, because it doesnt allow to monitor events while dragging).

Code in the `onCreate`:

```
//find UI
myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

//assign touch listener
myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

Code for `MyTouchListener`:

```
class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        //last coordinates
        float lastX;
        float lastY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    view.bringToFront();
                    lastX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                    lastY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    //motion difference
                    float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - lastX;
                    float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - lastY;

                    //set new last coordinates
                    lastX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                    lastY = motionEvent.getRawY();

                    //animate view to new location
                    view.animate().translationXBy(deltaX).translationYBy(deltaY).setDuration(0).start();

                    //get Rects
                    Rect textViewRect = new Rect((int)lastX+myTextView.getLeft(), (int)lastY+myTextView.getTop(), (int)lastX+myTextView.getRight(), (int)lastY+myTextView.getBottom());
                    Rect imageViewRect = new Rect(myImageView.getLeft(), myImageView.getTop(), myImageView.getRight(), myImageView.getBottom());


                    if (imageViewRect.intersect(textViewRect)) {
                        myImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));
                    } else {
                        myImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_delete));
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the lastX and lastY offsets for textViewRect but not imageViewRect? Have you tried removing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animated translation is unnecessary since the touch events should move the TextView smoothly about. Just assign new X,Y coordinates to the TextView, like this:

```
view.setX(view.getX() + deltaX);
view.setY(view.getY() + deltaY);
```

Comment: You're correct about replacing 'animate()' - I can drag it by setting X, Y, but that still doesnt change behaviour regarding detection of one view being dragged over another.

Comment: I understand that something is wrong with coordinates. I managed to find out that I need to account for Activity Bar and Status Bar height when retrieving getRawY and when setting the Rect of dragged view, but still cant get Rects to intersect correctly :(.

Comment: Which view are you receiving touch events from? You should be using whatever View is the parent of the Views you're dragging or intersecting with.

Comment: I've set touch listener to the view that I'm dragging (textView). If I would assign touch listener to the parent view, then local variable "view" inside listener would not refer to the dragged view. How would I determine if the dragged view is touched?

Comment: You may be missing move events if the TextView doesn't keep up with the user's finger. That's why it's important not to animate. Have you tried that yet? Also, see my comment in your OP.