# Why I get this difference of height values?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-titlebar, android-statusbar

My screen is 1080x1920. Height of green line is 1794, red line - 63 (status bar) + 84 (TitleBar) = 147, violet line - 1584. Why I dont get height of green line by adding red one to the violet one?

[image]

Violet line represents height of relative layout and I find it with this code in the `onWindowFocusChanged()`:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);
Log.i(TAG, "Relative layout height: "+String.valueOf(relativeLayout.getHeight()));
```

Red line represents height of title bar and status bar and I find it with this code in the `onWindowFocusChanged()`:

```
Rect rectangle = new Rect();
Window window = getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int titleBarHeight= contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;

Log.i(TAG, "StatusBar Height= " + statusBarHeight + " , TitleBar Height = " + titleBarHeight);
```

Green line suppose to represent height of whole program? and I find it with this code in the `onWindowFocusChanged()`:

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Log.i(TAG, "mdisp: "+String.valueOf(mdisp));
Point mdispSize = new Point();
mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
int maxX = mdispSize.x;
int maxY = mdispSize.y;
Log.i(TAG, "Max X, Y: "+String.valueOf(maxX)+", "+String.valueOf(maxY));
```

XML layout file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="lt.wilkas.stackoverflowquestion.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: maybe some paddings? A shadow padding?

Comment: Maybe, but where do they apply? I'm trying to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187745/how-to-implement-detection-of-a-view-being-dragged-over-another-view but these inconsistencies in coordinates gets me confused :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your titlebar height is not correct. As you can see, your titlebar height is visually appearing more than twice the height of your statusbar. So please use different method to get your titlebar height.

You can get this like:

```
int whiteParentHeight = 0;
int titlebarHeight = 0;

public int getTitleBarHeight() {

whiteParent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                //noinspection deprecation
                whiteParent.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                whiteParent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }

            whiteParentHeight = whiteParent.getHeight();
            titlebarHeight = whiteParentHeight - getStatusBarHeight();

        }
    });

}


public int getStatusBarHeight() {

    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }

    return result;

}
```

or to find default titlebar height, you can use:

```
final TypedArray styledAttributes = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
mActionBarSize = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
styledAttributes.recycle();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What is the whiteparent here? Is it the main relativeLayout?

Comment: I get the same 63 for the status bar, but 0 for the status bar.

Comment: status bar height will be the same, we are calculating here the height of title bar

Comment: Value of titlebarHeight  stays 0

Comment: can you please show me your xml layout file for above design?

Comment: Added XML contents. The value for margins is 16dp I think.

Comment: Ok. This is your default title bar as per theme you have selected. You can remove this header by changes the theme (e.g. NoActionBar or No TitleBar) and create your own Title bar into the layout xml file. Which will help you to get the write dimensions for your app.

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt help. I'm to new to create my own bar yet :) And I am aware of possibility to hide the bar, maybe I'll turn to this solution, if any other wont help.

Comment: Yeah sure. I have edited my answer, please go through it.